# Ajax pass parameter to page

Tags: ajax, database, jsp

I have a JSP page that I retrieve with AJAX. The JSP page has embedded queries that are executed and then rendered as tables. Each execute/render displays the first 100 results.

Is there a way to pass parameters to the queries in the JSP page as a part of my AJAX call?
Say, for example, if I wanted to query the database again with a different SQL for the next 100 results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How are you calling the page with ajax?  Like this: `http://www.mypage.jsp`

Then you could use a querystring -- like this: `http://www.mypage.jsp?name=John+Smith`

And then in your jsp page, you could have a function like this:

```
<%
    if (request.getParameter("name") == null) {
        out.println("Oops -- no data found.");
    } else {
        out.println("Howdy <b>"+request.getParameter(i)+"</b>!");
    }
%>
```